# Bevel not beveling in some cases - message is nothing selected

Tags: bevel

I use blender 2.8, this is my first project.
Problem is that I can not bevel in some cases.

I'm in edit mode, I select an edge and press CTRL+B and when I try to move the mouse to bevel I receive the message "Nothing selected" like in the image.
The blender file is [here](http://cc123.caido.ro/handle.blend).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 problems that prevent you to create any bevel:

- An inner face that you need to delete.
- A flipped normal, select all and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to fix it.

Now it works.

[image]